# ScrollToTop by navigation change doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in react and i tried to write a functional component for scrolling to the top of a page, when i navigate to this page from another page where i scrolled down.
The problem is, that the opened page doesn't scroll to the top when i navigate to it.

I used [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration) and [this](https://medium.com/@romanonthego/scroll-to-top-with-react-router-and-react-hooks-87ae21785d2f) tutorial.

Thats the function:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      window.scroll({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
    } catch (error) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }, [pathname]);
  console.log(pathname);

  return null;
}
```

And here i call it in the App.js. The tutorials say that it should be called under the router.

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "emotion-theming";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import GlobalStyles from "./GlobalStyles";
import { theme } from "./themes/theme";
import AppBar from "./components/Navigation/AppBar";
import FooterNav from "./components/Navigation/FooterNav";
import { MenuLink, BottomLink, FooterLink } from "./components/Navigation/NavLinks";
import Registration from "./pages/Registration";
import Program from "./pages/Program";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Workshops from "./pages/Workshops";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import Impressum from "./pages/Impressum";
import Privacy from "./pages/Privacy";
import Attendees from "./pages/Attendees";
import ConferenceFee from "./pages/ConferenceFee";
import { Main } from "./components/Container/Main";
import { PageContainer } from "./components/Container/PageContainer";
import HeaderImage from "./components/Images";
import ScrollToTop from "./components/ScrollToTop";

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <PageContainer>
        <Router>

          <ScrollToTop />

        <GlobalStyles />
          <AppBar>
            <MenuLink to="/">Start</MenuLink>
            <MenuLink to="/registration">Anmelden</MenuLink>
            <MenuLink to="/conferencefee">Tagungsbeitrag</MenuLink>
            <MenuLink to="/workshops">Workshops</MenuLink>
            <MenuLink to="/program">Tagungsprogramm</MenuLink>
            <MenuLink to="/contact">Kontakt/Tagungsbüro</MenuLink>
            <MenuLink to="/impressum">Impressum</MenuLink>
            <MenuLink to="/Privacy">Datenschutz</MenuLink>
          </AppBar>
          <Switch>
            <Main>
              <HeaderImage />
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Home />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/registration">
                <Registration />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/conferencefee">
                <ConferenceFee />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/program">
                <Program />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/workshops">
                <Workshops />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/contact">
                <Contact />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/impressum">
                <Impressum />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/privacy">
                <Privacy />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/attendees">
                <Attendees />
              </Route>
            </Main>
          </Switch>
          <FooterNav>
            <FooterLink to="/impressum">Impressum</FooterLink>
            <FooterLink to="/privacy">Datenschutz</FooterLink>
            <BottomLink to="/attendees">Orga-Login</BottomLink>
          </FooterNav>
        </Router>
      </PageContainer>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Maybe somebody knows, whats wrong?

Comment: Wrapping everything inside of the `ScrollToTop` leads to an empty white screen. So that doesnt seems to be the solution.
Thanks for thinking with me :)

The tutorial show it like this:

`function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <App />
    </Router>
  );
}`

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you just need to wrap everything inside `Router` with `ScrollToTop`, instead of just putting an empty component within `Router`.